# Excel macro to prepare query string based on rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have one excel Sheet having below records

id  Empname  state

1   steve     NJ

2  karl       NYC

I have to write one macro to prepare sql update stement like below and insert into new sheet within the same workbook.

```
UPDATE emp SET state='NJ' WHERE id=1
UPDATE emp SET state='NYC' WHERE id=2
```

Any suggestions or ideas please.

Regards,

Raju

Comment: Do you wish to update a set of records one by one using, say, ADO? What are the rules for writing the statements? Why is `1` and `NJ` significant but `steve` is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below sub and you should be all set

```
Sub generateUpdate()

Dim myRow As Integer: myRow = 2  'Starting Row of data in source table
Dim temp As Integer: temp = 1

Do Until Sheet1.Cells(myRow, 1) = "" 'Loop until you find a blank
'Do Until myRow = 5 '5 is Row number till while you wish to loop

Sheet2.Cells(temp, 1) = "UPDATE emp SET state='" & Sheet1.Cells(myRow, 3) & "' where id = " & Sheet1.Cells(myRow, 1)

myRow = myRow + 1
temp = temp + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi krusaint,Can you help me for the new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533300/excel-macro-to-comparison-of-rows

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with formulas; there's no need to write a macro (if I read your requirements correctly).

If your data is in `Sheet1!A2:C3`, then on `Sheet2` you could start in cell `A1` with the formula:

```
="UPDATE emp SET state = '" & Sheet1!C2 & "' WHERE id = " & Sheet1!A2
```

And then extend the formula down the column to repeat the pattern. After that you can simply copy the cells and paste the query into wherever you're going to use it.

Comment: :already other functionality running in macros,so here I have to write aacro ,it should insert these update statements into new sheet