# Excel macro to comparison of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do below example, not able to do it.

Excel Data in Sheet1:

```
id     Sysid     option      status
XYZ      XT       Open       status_1
US     XT       Close      Status_1
US      XT       Open       Stauts_2
NJ      XT       Open   Status_2
IND     VX       Close      Status_1
BAN     VX       Open       Status_1
CHN     XY       Open       Status_1
YST     xy       Close      Status_1
```

In above data Status_1 and Sysid defines unique record,Based on this condition i have to find out which records have open and close difference for that unique record combination. If options are different I have to copy that data to different sheet using excel macro.This should work only for id's US and CHN.Suppose if id has US ,it should compare with matching record based on sysid and Status.  Any help appreciated.

Output Like below:

```
 XYZ      XT       Open       status_1
 US     XT       Close      Status_1
 CHN     XY       Open       Status_1
 YST     xy       Close      Status_1
```

Comment: How would you define an "open and close difference"?  Maybe you could edit your question to show which record(s) qualify...

Comment: @Tim:Already i mentioned in my question.Based on Sysid and status

Comment: You can do a lot with ADO and Excel. All sorts of fairly complex queries are possible.

Comment: @Remou:Tim already given answer for this,But few changes required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited to include test for "US" or "CHN"

```
Sub Tester()

Const COL_ID As Integer = 1
Const COL_SYSID As Integer = 2
Const COL_STATUS As Integer = 4
Const COL_OPTION As Integer = 3
Const VAL_DIFF As String = "XXdifferentXX"

Dim d As Object, sKey As String, id As String
Dim rw As Range, opt As String, rngData As Range
Dim rngCopy As Range, goodId As Boolean
Dim FirstPass As Boolean, arr

    With Sheet1.Range("A1")
        Set rngData = .CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Resize( _
                         .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1)
    End With
    Set rngCopy = Sheet1.Range("F2")

    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    FirstPass = True

redo:
    For Each rw In rngData.Rows

        sKey = rw.Cells(COL_SYSID).Value & "<>" & _
               rw.Cells(COL_STATUS).Value

        If FirstPass Then
          'Figure out which combinations have different option values
          '  and at least one record with id=US or CHN
          id = rw.Cells(COL_ID).Value
          goodId = (id = "US" Or id = "CHN")
          opt = rw.Cells(COL_OPTION).Value

          If d.exists(sKey) Then
              arr = d(sKey) 'can't modify the array in situ...
              If arr(0) <> opt Then arr(0) = VAL_DIFF
              If goodId Then arr(1) = True
              d(sKey) = arr 'return [modified] array
          Else
              d.Add sKey, Array(opt, goodId)
          End If

        Else
          'Second pass - copy only rows with varying options
          '  and id=US or CHN
          If d(sKey)(0) = VAL_DIFF And d(sKey)(1) = True Then
              rw.Copy rngCopy
              Set rngCopy = rngCopy.Offset(1, 0)
          End If
        End If

    Next rw
    If FirstPass Then
        FirstPass = False
        GoTo redo
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: :Thanks for your answer.I edited my question,Based on that it needs one more condition before comparison.Please help me on this.

Comment: :Hardly i understand VB code finally,In your above code while preparing key id also should include with the condition one of the id value should be either "US" or "CH".Please give me any hints

Comment: That should be a very simple edit: right now it joins two values for the key, and you just need to add a third.  And add an If..Then directly inside the 'For Each rw ... Next rw' loop to test for the 'id' value.

Comment: :Thanks tim,I tried to add IF then and Do Loop Condition,But Both not worked.COuld you please edit the answer.I edited My question also.

Comment: See my edits.  Untested, but if it needs tweaking it will be a good exercise for you.  Don't forget to accept my answer...

Comment: :It is not working.Problem is with condition  If id = "US" Or id = "CHN".if id is US or CHN it will go inside,But it is not going for correspondig record with matching sysid and status.Could you please check my input and output data in my question.

Comment: I think here checking id has US or CHN is not a solution.

Comment: I think here checking id has US or CHN is not a solution.Solution should be i have to add two records with same status and sysyid but one of the record in id should be US or CHN.

Comment: HI Tim,I tried to test key while adding values into new excel sheet.But it failed somehow.

Comment: :Just extended to my earlier question,After findingout matching records in Sheet 1,How to highlight with some color in Sheet1?

Comment: Geeting Subscript out of range error in this line  If arr(0) <> opt,when i checked count of array it is showing 2.I able to access the arr(1),arr(2).But with arr(0).it is giving error

Answer (score 1):

Use the macro recorder and do a unique advanced filter on the data then you can do your comparisons.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-for-unique-records-HP003073425.aspx?CTT=3

Comment: @Raju - Jon is suggesting you use the macro recorder to get a start with your code...

Comment: @Tim:I know basic things,how to create macro and record it.But i dont know VB Api.Which functions to use to compare and what approach i have to follow.